# monaca の連絡先プラグイン利用でエラー

Tags: monaca

monaca で、連絡先プラグインを利用しようと思い、サンプルコードをお手本に、

```
<script>
function contacts_success(contacts) {
    alert(contacts.length
        + ' contacts returned.'
        + (contacts[2] && contacts[2].name ?
              (' Third contact is ' +   contacts[2].name.formatted) :
              ''));
}
function contacts_failed(msgObject){
    alert("Failed to access contact list:" + JSON.stringify(msgObject));
}
function get_contacts() {
    var obj = new ContactFindOptions();
    obj.filter = "";
    obj.multiple = true;
　  navigator.contacts.find(
        [ "displayName", "name" ], contacts_success,
        contacts_failed, obj);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="get_contacts();return false;">Get Phone's Contacts</a>
</body>
```

は正常に実行されました。これを、起動されたときに実行したいので、

```
<script>
function contacts_success(contacts) {
    alert(contacts.length
        + ' contacts returned.'
        + (contacts[2] && contacts[2].name ? (' Third contact is ' + contacts[2].name.formatted)
                : ''));
}
function contacts_failed(msgObject){
    alert("Failed to access contact list:" + JSON.stringify(msgObject));
}

var obj = new ContactFindOptions();
obj.filter = "";
obj.multiple = true;
navigator.contacts.find(
    [ "displayName", "name" ], contacts_success,
    contacts_failed, obj);
</script>
```

としたところ

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。
なぜなんでしょうか。。。

Answer (score 1):

`ContactFindOptions`を定義しているファイル(Cordova)を読み込む前に処理が走るせいではないでしょうか。

```
// Cordova の読み込み完了まで待機
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova 準備完了
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var obj = new ContactFindOptions();
    obj.filter = "";
    obj.multiple = true;
    navigator.contacts.find(
        [ "displayName", "name" ],
        contacts_success, contacts_failed, obj);
}
```

などとするのはどうでしょう。

cf. [連絡先 - Monacaドキュメント](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/phonegap_29/ja/contacts/contacts/#contactfindoptions-ja)